# Reading EXIF gives an error

Tags: python-3.x, imagemagick, wand

I'm trying to print the EXIF of an image.
This is my code:

```
with Image(filename="/home/hapoofesgeli/Desktop/b.jpg") as image:
    for k, v in image.metadata.items():
        if k.startswith('exif:'):
            print(k, v)
```

But it it gives an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hapoofesgeli/Programming/Test/Test.py", line 5, in <module>
    for k, v in image.metadata.items():
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/collections/abc.py", line 480, in __iter__
    yield (key, self._mapping[key])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/wand/image.py", line 2260, in __getitem__
    raise TypeError('k must be a string, not ' + repr(format))
TypeError: k must be a string, not <built-in function format>
```

How to solve this error?

Comment: This seems a bug, and fixed in master: https://github.com/dahlia/wand/commit/11235ee204a48e060498e63a9171c55c1ba808d4

Comment: So it was a bug...Thanks.

Comment: Sorry by how should i use the fixed version?i replaced the old image.py and tests/image_test.py with the new ones and installed it using python setup.py install. but now i get this error: ImportError: cannot import name encode_filename

Comment: Try pip install git+git@github.com/dahlia/wand.git@0.3-maintenance#egg=Wand-0.3.2dev

Comment: pip gives an error(Expected version spec) but i downloaded wand-0.3-maintenance.zip and installed it using python install and that python code finally works.Thanks

Comment: Oh there was a typo, it should be git+git://github.com/dahlia/wand.git@0.3-maintenance#egg=Wand-0.3.2dev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use the `_getexif()` method of that comes bundled in PIL's Image module:

```
>>> image = Image.open(os.getcwd() + '/canon-ixus.jpg')
>>> image._getexif()
{36864: '0210', 37121: '\x01\x02\x03\x00', .... }
```

or also `image.info['exif']`:

```
>>> image.info['exif'][0:20]
'Exif\x00\x00II*\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\t\x00\x0f\x01\x02\x00'
```

Comment: also, I've never seen `image.metadata` being used anywhere else (but I may be wrong, I hope) Tried that out on a bunch of images, they all seem to miss that, no matter what I try

Comment: I'm using Python 3 so there is no PIL.
And I've written that code according to this page:
https://wand.readthedocs.org/en/0.3-maintenance/whatsnew/0.3.html
the Exif part.

Comment: You could still use Pillow, the friendly PIL fork: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/

Comment: Thanks to your help I can get the result of image._getexif()
But how should i use that result?

Comment: How were you planning to use it in your original post? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to get some information such as ISO, Exposure time and after that use them to do other things...